# unexplainable behaviour

Tags: biblatex

There is no problem to be solved here, I just experienced a very strange behaviour on the part of latex - have you ever experienced something similar?

After having made a clean new installation of Ubuntu 12.04 (I moved from Mint 10), I set to work upon a tex file that I had used on the old OS. Then, somehow, without any change in the file, `\textcite{X}` produced not, as it used to, `X (year)` but `X (title)`. I then started to make a minimal example, but could not reproduce the new output, but got what I wanted `X (year)`, even after including the whole preamble. Then, I run again pdflatex, biblatex (2x), pdflatex (2x) on the original document, and I got what I wanted. The strange thing is that I got two different outputs from the original file, without changing a letter in the file nor in the installation. 
So, after all, there is no problem, just an hour or so wasted.

Has anyone made similar experiences? 
Or has someone an explanation for this? (Other than me being silly)

Comment: Never experienced it, but suspect is different versions of packages. Search for Ubuntu as to how to update the TeX distribution.

Comment: During the hour you changed auxiliary files (which could contain remains from older versions of your file), you perhaps also changed the location of the file - document folders can contain forgotten bst and style files.

Comment: I copied the whole folder from the old system. Hm, so maybe it was a new tex distribution getting mixed up in the auxiliary files (which were originally produced in the old OS), and I got it right after making a full run. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: TeXLive2009 is the default in Ubuntu 12.04. You can install  TeXLive 2012 from the official 12.10 [backports](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012) ppa. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu